# I am not able to use the router in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router-dom

I have been trying to use a router on react project but getting an error :

A Route is only ever to be used as the child of Routes element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your Route in a Routes.

The Code Is Shown Below

```
import About from "./container/About";
import Profile from "./container/Profile";
import { useState } from "react";
import {BrowserRouter as Routes,Route} from 'react-router-dom'
function App(){
  const [state, setState] = useState('')
  return(
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={()=>setState('about')}>About</button>
      <button onClick={()=>setState('profile')}>Profile</button>
      <Routes>
        <Route component={About} path='/about'></Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  )
}
export default App;
```

Comment: You've incorrectly imported `BrowserRouter as Routes`, so the `Route` component is *actually* wrapped by a router instead of the expected `Routes` components, and thus the error. Voting to close as "unreproducible or caused by typo". Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on version 6 of `react-router-dom`, you need to name the props differently:

`<Route element={About} path='/about'></Route>`

In version 5, it was named `component`.

I assume you're on version 6, because I can't remember version 5 having the `Routes` component. Also, you need to import the components differently, and wrap everything with the BrowserRouter.

```
import About from "./container/About";
import Profile from "./container/Profile";
import { useState } from "react";
import {BrowserRouter, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
function App(){
  const [state, setState] = useState('')
  return(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={()=>setState('about')}>About</button>
        <button onClick={()=>setState('profile')}>Profile</button>
        <Routes>
          <Route element={<About />} path='/about'></Route>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Yes, on version 6. Still getting the same error now

Comment: I didn't spot it at first, but there's a problem with the way you import the router components. I edited my answer to hopefully address everything.

Comment: This error came back:Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

Comment: Ah! `<Route element={<About />} path='/about'></Route>`

This should do it

Comment: It Worked!. So We Have To Pass It As A Component Inside The Element. Right??

Comment: You pass in elements just as you would use them inside the jsx (including the `<...>` tags. And you can pass props to them as well

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can call the `BrowserRouter` component the way you did in your code. Perhaps if you wrap your code in the router - in a way that it's the topmost parent, such as [this example](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/routers/browser-router) and render your buttons inside of it then it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Put the path before the component

```
    <Route path='/about' element={About}></Route>
```

Also ,

Wrap your  in the index.js file with `BrowserRouter`

```
<BrowserRouter>
<App/>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Still Getting The Same Error Now

Comment: Check my edited answer